# Process not showing up in "ps -e" output

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, sh, redhat

I am very confused because I have just launched this single line:

```
while sleep 10; do curl http://somewhere:8888 >> out.log; done &
```

I closed the session, opened it again with same user (root), and I don't see the process anymore whey I do:

```
ps -ef
```

BUT the file "out.log" is still being updated!
Where is this process hidden?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for in the `ps` output?

Comment: I am looking fot the line (grep curl, for example)

Comment: `curl` will only run every now and then, so it’s no surprise you can run `ps` without seeing it.

Comment: You will see your shell and `sleep`, `curl` only runs every 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way, you do the redirection:

```
while sleep 10; do curl http://somewhere:8888; done >> out.log &
```

You can easily find the processes with:

```
lsof out.log
```

This is probably also more efficient.